# How to get values of a multidimensional array with a string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array

```
$array[0]["searched0"] = "text0";
$array[1]["searched1"] = "text1";
...
```

Now I want to get "text1" but I only know it is $array[1] but not the name  "searched1". Is there a possibility to get the searched parameter?

Comment: You can use PHP's new function `array_key_first` `echo $array[1][array_key_first($array[1])];`

Comment: If I correctly understand, as you know first part of array maybe `array_search("text1", $array[1])` will help. It will return first found key for search string. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: How many other key values are in each sub array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) you get the first element.

```
echo reset($array[1]);  //text1
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will help you

```php
$searchedElement = "text1"; 

foreach (array[0] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $searchedElement) {
        echo $key;
        break;  // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Php.